# Joining on a varchar to a char does not work in JPA (oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, oracle10g, varchar2

I have an *existing* DB that two tables are joined based on a string.  The problem is that one table column is defined as a varchar2 and the other is a char.  Oracle will pad the char with spaces and the varchar2 will not so that when ***JPA*** tries to join the two one has space and one does not so the equality is not met.

How can I get the join to work in ***JPA***?
Is there a ***JPA*** annotation that would do the trick?

Comment: "JPA" is an interface; it doesn't do anything so can't work or otherwise. Maybe it doesn't work with your *implementation* (you don't say which one), but maybe it works with a different implementation. Without your definition of the "problem" its all pointless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to use @Subselect.

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table( schema="SECURITYDBO", name = "XREFERENCE")
@Subselect("SELECT " + 
        " ,cast( trim(aCharColumn) as varchar(100) )  AS aCharColumn" + // NEED TO TRIM SO THAT JPA INNER JOINED BETWEEN 2 tables WHICH IS A VARCHAR AND THIS ONE THERE WILL NOT BE ANY SPACES PADDED  
        "FROM MYTABLE ")
public class MyJPA extends XReference{
....